# Android Studio with itext library

Tags: android, pdf, itext

How to get valuees from user and fill into a fixed Form.
For eg:
A form contain name address and all, user need to enter values to corresponding blank field and that values is filled and convert into pdf.

And i find that itext can solve this problem but im not familiar with it so please help

Comment: Can you explain what you tried and what didn't work for you ?

Comment: i only heard about the term itext i dont how to work with that